# Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?

Tags: php, sql-server, localhost

I need to retrieve a user's IP. My localhost is returning `::1` as the IP. I am curious, if this is an expected behaviour? I'm running MAMP on Snow Leopard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP $_SERVER\['REMOTE_HOST'\] returns ::1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482033/php-serverremote-host-returns-1)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Same question, and found a valid solution, tested, works well. I wanted to have the ip addy - of 127.0.0.1 as well instead of having to accept the the ::1 and debate the whole IPv4/6 issues.  So, i trolled for a few moments and fell onto a 2008 comment made by @Brad - here:
http://board.issociate.de/thread/489575/SERVERquotREMOTEADDRquot-returning-1.html

Summarizing - (on Mac OS - Mountain Lion in particular)

`sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Find where your apache is 'listen'-ing to the ips/ports, etc... 
Typically this will be a line looking like this

`Listen 80`

Make it look like this:

`Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

Resave it.
Restart Apache.
Voila!

Now `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]` will look like this `127.0.0.1`.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: "Listen 127.0.0.1:80" you mean :)

Comment: This way you are disabling IPv6 support for Apache. You can fix it another way: add ``127.0.0.1 localhost`` to hosts file, so IPv4 resolution is priorized over IPv6 for localhost ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything o El Capitan with MAMP 3.5

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena I've got that on the first line of hosts, still get ::1 in PHP.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian what IP shows when you ping localhost?

Answer (score 31):

`::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of IPv4 `127.0.0.1` address.

You can convert IPv6 address to IPv4 address using function `inet_ntop()` as Adam, said.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php

Comment: I believe you can convert between IPv4 and IPv6 using `inet_ntop`

Comment: @adam, yes, you are right. @Mild: if you are satisfied with my answer, please accept ;]

Comment: $ip=inet_ntop($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);  is returning Warning: inet_ntop() [function.inet-ntop]: Invalid in_addr value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/createstudios/wp-content/themes/createstudios/page.php on line 18

Comment: Was your PHP library built with IPv6 support?

Comment: and, ultimately, does it matter? Are these values good enough?

Comment: I don;t know if unprepared IPv6 string can be input for inet_ntop(). There is some preparing going down in manual - see comments, maybe they will enlighten you a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or even `/private/etc/hosts` isn't the solution. It's returning ::1 because it's the IPv6 equivalent to the old (but gold) IPv4's `127.0.0.1`. As it's defined in the `/privates/etc/hosts`, whenever you access `http://localhost` it assumes IPv6 ::1. So it's the expected behavior.

A workaround would be to access `http://127.0.0.1` directly. It'll work just fine. But remember that IPv6 availability is increasing. You could make sure your server (after deployment) will only respond to IPv4 but in the mid term, if your site/web app does not handle both IPv4 and IPv6 properly, there's a great chance something will go wrong within 1/2 years. Or sooner, we never know.

Answer (score 2):

for who has not reslove this issue it sounds that the `hosts` file is missing or the line

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

in `etc\hosts` LINUX

in  `/private/etc/hosts` MAC devices

in `\%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`  WINDOWS xp/vista/7/8/

whene the file `hosts` is removed or `missed` or the line too the `IPV6` will be set by `default` ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable IPv6 support in your OS for apache to stop showing these IPv6 format addresses, when you want the IPv4 format. I disabled IPv6 support and its working as expected now.

I recently ran into this issue, though i don't ever remember enabling ipv6 support on my Windows 7 system, could be done by Microsoft in one of their updates (maybe).

Comment: I believe that IPv6 has been enabled by default since Windows XP SP2 or even earlier.