# How to get value 127.0.0.1 rather than ::1 on php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

I want to get value 127.0.0.1 when do $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. 
But instead getting 127.0.0.1. I get value ::1. Anyone can help me how to get that value? Used it for log activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

::1 is an IPv6 address and an abbreviation for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 that is the loopback address to the local machine. So ::1 is the same as 127.0.0.1 only via IPv6 instead of IPv4.

If you really just want IPv4, try to disable IPv6 connections in your apache configuration:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 192.170.2.1:80
```

You can find detailed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-ip-serverremote-addr-return-1-on-a-mamp-localhost)

Comment: hmm i see. then i cant get value 127.0.0.1? i want to save it in database, and then show it in the log activity page. Show in log activity page using 127.0.0.1 is better than show ::1

Comment: or maybe i must get IPv$ instead of IPv6?

Comment: You can just check the link which I have added with the answer. You just need to change your .conf settings and restart the server.

Comment: go to terminal and type sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and then change the configuration

Comment: iam looking httpd.conf, and then open with notepad++. Terminal = command prompt u means? because when iam type that in cmd didnt work

Comment: but anyway its solved, now just curious how to edit using sudo vi.

Comment: Yes you should go to command prompt and then open the httpd.conf using the command i just told