# Getting IP address with PHP to display correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to use the time and **IP** address to generate unique ID for users as they register for the site. The DB I'm using is `MySQL` and it comes with auto increment, but it doesn't seem like a practical technique for this. I am having issues with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returning an unreadable address. I'm getting symbols for the value in the firebug console. I tried using `inet_ntop` and `inet_pton`, neither worked.

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$test = inet_ntop($ip_address);
echo($test);
```

Why am I getting symbols instead of readable text?

EDIT:

What I want to store is a combination of the IP and time. I need the IP to show in format of "79.104.97.105" -Niet the Dark Absol, but what I'm getting is ��������������� if I use use inet_ntop or inet_pton or ::1 if I use just $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Two part question: 1) Am I getting the IP address as IPv6 if it returns ::1, 2) How do I convert to 127.0.0.1 which I think is IPv4

Comment: It's because `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not packed. Do `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and you'll see. What is the output you're seeing.

Comment: Try `echo inet_pton("79.104.97.105")` - this may give you a hint as to what's going on ;)

Comment: it returned ::1
I understand that this is suppose to be because it's IPv6, but I need it in the full format like IPv4.

Comment: Yes, but I need the format to change to full readable text. Since this is a local server, it should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: @user2812097 I updated my answer for "readable text".

Comment: Are you trying to convert IPv6 to IPv4 ??? IPv4 is not the "full format" version of IPv6.. I suggest wikipedia lookup IPv6.

Comment: I added to the question to break down into 2 questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inet_ntop()` expects  the address in a binary format.

[Example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php):

```
$packed = chr(127) . chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(1);
$expanded = inet_ntop($packed);

/* Outputs: 127.0.0.1 */
echo $expanded;
```

You need to use `inet_pton()` instead, which expects the IP in for format in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

**Update**

In the question you state that you need the address in readable format.

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

The variable already contains the IP in human readable format, no need for any PHP function to convert it.

Comment: When I use that this is the return statement: ���������������

Comment: Well, `inet_pton` converts the IP into binary format, so you see this. Maybe you should expand the question on what you actually want to store in the database.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider He edited the question: `::1 if I use just $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].`

Comment: Well, one can just accept that `::1` is just as valid as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I think I needed both, I was getting the symbols and the ::1
I wasn't sure if I was doing it right because anywhere I look said it was 127.0.0.1 no matter if IPv4 or IPv6. Now that I know for sure that I'm getting the IP, how do I convert it? Guess it was a two part question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function :

```
function getRealIP(){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

**EDIT**

This question may help you I think he had the same issue : [Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-ip-serverremote-addr-return-1-on-a-mamp-localhost)

Comment: It's always good to check all headers for proxies +1, but the answer 1. has no explanation 2. is not related to the OPs question -1.

Comment: Well, OP said : `I am having issues with $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] returning an unreadable address.` when I echo the function a printed here I get clear IP address @127. 0.0.1 so to me, it's related sorry if isn't wasn't a bad intention.

Comment: Well, OP has written a confusing question there but read his edit. He is getting `::1` from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Thank for your comment I have edited my answer to link a similar problem.

Comment: I tried inet_ntop like in the link you post in your edit and I'm getting the symbols. Why am I getting symbols and not 127.0.0.1?

Comment: hmm maybe the page charset ? try to set `charset=utf-8`

html version : `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

php version : `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`