# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not returning ip address

Tags: php, ip-address

I am using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in php to find client's `ip address`.

```
$ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

echo $ipaddress;
```

which return ::1

I also tried the following code,but that gives me same result as well.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
```

What am I doing wrong?How can I get clients ip?

I would use the ip to find client's location via `ipinfo.io`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `::1` is valid ipv6 localhost address

Comment: When I use `$idaddress` in script to get location using `ipinfo.io`,I get `undefined property: stdclass::$country`.Anyway,I need the full ip address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::1` is the actual IP. It is an ipv6 address (i.e. localhost). If you were using ipv4 it would be `127.0.0.1.`

If you want to get a different IP address, then you'll need to connect to the server through a different network interface.

Comment: When I use `$idaddress` in script to get location using `ipinfo.io`,I get `undefined property: stdclass::$country`.

Comment: If I put this same script on server now,will it work and give me my full ip address?

Comment: Yes please check the host file

Comment: I didn't get you.What'd u mean by host file?can u pls clarify

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost

Comment: I just uploaded it on server,and it is working.Thanks a lot.Bye the way,should I use just `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or the 2nd piece of code to find ip?