# How can I show the Person his Ip with PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I want that the Person can see their Ip.I already have tried with

```
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

didnt work.other things also not pls help.

Comment: `<?php print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>`?

Comment: *didnt work.other things also not* What is not working, what is the expected output and what do you get? What other things does not work. This question is very vague.

Comment: maybe you can show what your output when `var_dump($_SERVER)`. maybe can help.

Comment: I open localhost and this comes (   ::1   )!!!

Comment: This comes up in the first example ::1

Comment: The IP address of localhost **is** ::1. When you put the web site online it'll show the user's IP address because they're not accessing the site through localhost.

Comment: second example: really long code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_SERVER\['REMOTE\_ADDR'\] is not returning ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618903/serverremote-addr-is-not-returning-ip-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
function get_client_ip() {

        $ip = "";

        if ($_SERVER) {
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }
            elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
            else {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
        }
        else {
            if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
                $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
            }
            elseif (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
                $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
            }
            else {
                $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
            }
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

Hope it is help. :)