# Magento getRemoteAddr returns junk as IP in localhost

Tags: php, magento

I want to get the visitor's(users) ip address, for which i have tried like below:

```
$remoteAddr = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($remoteAddr); echo "</pre>";
```

Im running on Xampp in windows and the above code returns output like below which is not even like ::1  (Tried in all browsers too!!)

[image]

Is the code right in magento.

I found out the below stackposts to see the fix why localhost returns ::1 which is equivalent of ipV6 address

[Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost)

I did change the apache2/httpd.conf

> Listen 80

**Make it look like this:**

> Listen 127.0.0.1:80

But it still displays the same.

Is it right in localhost?